# How to define variable as lambda function

Tags: c#, lambda

(Lambda function may or may not be what I'm looking for, I'm not sure)

Essentially what I'm trying to accomplish is this:

```
int areaOfRectangle = (int x, int y) => {return x * y;};
```

but it gives error: "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'int' because it is not a delegate type"

The more detailed problem (that really has nothing to do with the question, but I know someone will ask) is:

I have several functions that branch from an overridden OnLayout and several more functions that each of those depend on. For readability and to set precedent for later expansion, I want the functions that branch from OnLayout to all look similar. To do that, I need to compartmentalize them and reuse naming as much as possible:

```
protected override void OnLayout(LayoutEventArgs levent)
    switch (LayoutShape)
    {
        case (square):
            doSquareLayout();
            break;
        case (round):
            doRoundLayout();
            break;
        etc..
        etc..
    }
void doSquareLayout()
{
    Region layerShape = (int Layer) =>
    {
        //do some calculation
        return new Region(Math.Ceiling(Math.Sqrt(ItemCount)));
    }
    int gradientAngle = (int itemIndex) =>
    {
        //do some calculation
        return ret;
    }
    //Common-ish layout code that uses layerShape and gradientAngle goes here
}
void doRoundLayout()
{
    Region layerShape = (int Layer) =>
    {
        //Do some calculation
        GraphicsPath shape = new GraphicsPath();
        shape.AddEllipse(0, 0, Width, Height);
        return new Region(shape);
    }
    int gradientAngle = (int itemIndex) =>
    {
        //do some calculation
        return ret;
    }
    //Common-ish layout code that uses layerShape and gradientAngle goes here
}
```

All the examples I find right now say you have to declare a delegate but I *know* I've seen a one liner lambda declaration...

Comment: There is no equivalent to C++ `inline`. If you're looking for a one line function definition, yes, that's possible. (see my answer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `Func<int, int, int> areaOfRectangle = (int x, int y) => { return x * y;};` instead.

`Func` works as as delegate

[Look here for more info on lamda expression usage](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33323/Functional-Programming-in-C-3-0-using-Lambda-Expre)

[This answer is also related and has some good info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12267298/1048432)

If you're doing it for readability and are going to reproduce the same functions `layerShape` and `gradientAngle`, you might want to have explicit delegates for those functions to show they are in fact the same. Just a thought.

Comment: By the way, this is not the same as C++ `inline`

Answer (score 2):

Try like this;

```
Func<int, int, int> areaOfRectangle = (int x, int y) => { return x * y; };
```

Check *[`Func<T1, T2, TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534647.aspx)* from *MSDN*;

> Encapsulates a method that has two parameters and returns a value of
>   the type specified by the TResult parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The variable type is based on your parameters and return type:

```
Func<int,int,int> areaOfRectangle = (int x, int y) => {return x * y;};
```

Answer (score 1):

You're close:

```
Func<int, int, int> areaOfRectangle = (int x, int y) => {return x * y;};
```

So for your specific case your declaration would be:

```
Func<int, Region> layerShape = (int Layer) =>
...
```